# Node.js: Custom command line interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, command, command-line-interface

I'm very newbie in this thing. I would like to create a command line interface for my application where I can specify custom commands something like these:

```
myapp new /root/myapp
myapp start /server.js
myapp stop /server.js
```

So i can interact with my application just like I do with a real service like mysql. Is it possible to write such a service like thing inside node.js?

What I'm looking for something similar to [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) or [meteor](http://meteor.com/) in terms of working with them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What are you having trouble with? ([this](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) may help). Also, why not just read their code? ([forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/blob/master/lib/forever/cli.js))

Comment: thanks @tjameson I was reading their source code and they use flatiron  as a cli tool, however I still don't see how are they actually doing it without calling `node`. I mean you can use forever like this `forever start`, but as I read the flatiron docs, in every example it is like `node myapp.js -options`, so I don't really understand.

Comment: Notice the `#!` at the [top](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/blob/master/bin/forever)? When you `chmod +x` your file, the interpreter will check for this. This is saying it's a `node` file, so it executes it with node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify myapp in package.json like so:

```
{ "name": "myapp"
, "version": "0.0.1"
, "engines": [ "node >=0.4.0" ]
, "description": "myapp command line util."
, "author": "..."
, "contributors": []
, "keywords" : [ "myapp", "command", "shell" ]
, "repository":
  { "type" : "git"
  , "url" : "https://...."
  }
, "bin" : { "myapp" : "./bin/myapp.js" }
}
```

http://howtonode.org/how-to-module

Answer (score 0):

You can use commander module from npm for building your own CLI. Simply enter:

```
npm install commander
```

This will install commander module.

For examples and documentation, you can go through this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander